# I am trying to rebuild my old working project and this error is showing what to do?

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

Error:In  FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontVariationSettings
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process /sdk/build-tools/27.0.2/aapt with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I /sdk/platforms/android-26/android.jar -M /project/kitchen33app/milla/build/intermediates/manifest/androidTest/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -S /project/kitchen33app/milla/build/intermediates/res/merged/androidTest/debug -m -J /project/kitchen33app/milla/build/generated/source/r/androidTest/debug -F /project/kitchen33app/milla/build/intermediates/res/androidTest/debug/resources-debugAndroidTest.ap_ -0 apk --output-text-symbols /project/kitchen33app/milla/build/intermediates/symbols/androidTest/debug --no-version-vectors}
Error:com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process /sdk/build-tools/27.0.2/aapt with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I /sdk/platforms/android-26/android.jar -M /project/kitchen33app/milla/build/intermediates/manifest/androidTest/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -S /project/kitchen33app/milla/build/intermediates/res/merged/androidTest/debug -m -J /project/kitchen33app/milla/build/generated/source/r/androidTest/debug -F /project/kitchen33app/milla/build/intermediates/res/androidTest/debug/resources-debugAndroidTest.ap_ -0 apk --output-text-symbols /project/kitchen33app/milla/build/intermediates/symbols/androidTest/debug --no-version-vectors}
Error:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/sdk/build-tools/27.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Error:Execution failed for task ':milla:processDebugAndroidTestResources'.

> Failed to execute aapt

Answer (score 0):

Just replace referencing of color code with the actual color in vector drawable files and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In your app **build.gradle** add the following line:

```
defaultConfig{
   vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```